# How to remove duplicated (by name) column in data.tables in R?

Tags: r, data.table

While reading a data set using `fread`, I've noticed that sometimes I'm getting duplicated column names, for example (`fread` doesn't have `check.names` argument)

```
> data.table( x = 1, x = 2)
   x x
1: 1 2
```

**The question is:** is there any way to remove 1 of 2 columns if they have the same name?

Comment: @DavidArenburg - copied columns are a result of fread function that reads a file where are duplicated column names ;/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about

```
dt[, .SD, .SDcols = unique(names(dt))]
```

This selects the *first* occurrence of each name (I'm not sure how you want to handle this).

As @DavidArenburg suggests in comments above, you could use `check.names=TRUE` in `data.table()` or `fread()`

Comment: How do you remove duplicate columns when the content is duplicated but the name is not?

Answer (score 16):

`.SDcols` approaches would return a *copy* of the columns you're selecting. Instead just remove those duplicated columns using `:=`, by reference.

```
dt[, which(duplicated(names(dt))) := NULL]
#    x
# 1: 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Different approaches:

1. **Indexing**

   `my.data.table <- my.data.table[ ,-2]`
2. **Subsetting**

   `my.data.table <- subset(my.data.table, select = -2)`
3. **Making unique names** if 1. and 2. are not ideal (when having hundreds of columns, for instance)

   `setnames(my.data.table, make.names(names = names(my.data.table), unique=TRUE))`
4. **Optionnaly systematize deletion** of variables which names meet some criterion (here, we'll get rid of all variables having a name ending with ".X" (X being a number, starting at 2 when using `make.names`)

   `my.data.table <- subset(my.data.table, 
                      select = !grepl(pattern = "\\.\\d$", x = names(my.data.table)))`

Comment: what if i don't know the position, there are 1200 columns, and 7 of them has non unique names?

Comment: Then maybe rename the columns before deleting them. See `?make.names`

Comment: @BenBolker I tried with a data.table and it worked as expected.

Comment: weird. `dt <- data.table( x = 1:3, x = 2:4); dt[,-2]` returns -2 for me, I need `dt[,-2,with=FALSE]` to get the right answer. (data.table version 1.9.4)

Comment: As I recall you have to be careful with `names()<-` for data.table: `setnames()` is safer

Comment: Yup, boy I need to review my data.tables. Thx for catching this @BenBolker

Comment: Just `setnames(dt, make.names(names(dt), unique=TRUE))` will work.

Comment: Guys do you know how to do the same but for rows?

Comment: There are no row names in `data.table`... If you need to remove duplicates, use `unique`.

Comment: @MarcinKosinski And there can't be duplicate rownames in base R. Did you have a specific situation in mind?

Comment: One column has duplicated values. I'd like to extract only those rows that have unique values in that specific column.

Comment: `unique` has a `by` argument. I'd suggest you start reading some documentations or using Google.

Comment: @Marcin Probly worth asking a new question with some basic sample data.

Comment: @DavidArenburg this world is so amazing that it is faster to ask on stack and recieve answer than to look into 10-page-long vignette of data.tables package ;/

Comment: @MarcinKosinski not sure `unique` would help. You are looking for values that have only one occurence in the vector, right? So imagine you have `df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,12))` and want only rows corresponding to those values in b that occur only once. You'd get this with  `df[df$b %in% names(which(table(df$b)==1)),]`

Comment: Unique by Column from package data.tables worked fine Jason. @DavidArenburg I was Not aware that data.tables has it's unique unique function, untill I asked on SO :) thanks for help